# eclipse: C - Console Window Input

Tags: c, eclipse

In eclipse, how do I tell the console to submit the text? When I press enter, it just goes to a new line where I can continue typing and does not submit the text to continue processing.

Comment: I use Eclipse and I do not have that problem... Are you sure your code does not have a mistake?

Comment: I'm new to eclipse, but I am pretty certain it has nothing to do with my code. I'm using C (not Java) if that makes any difference.

Comment: I use C too... does that even happen if you read a character using getchar() to print it?

Comment: yes. I may be on the wrong track, but from the bits and pieces I have been reading it seems there is some bug in eclipse and I need to set "set new-console on" somewhere.. I think in a .gdbinit file, but I cannot find that anywhere. Can someone tell me exactly where to put that command? Explian in detail, because I have never used eclipse before. Thanks

Comment: One of the many of the bugs I have found in Eclipse... I've read all over the internet that NetBeans is much better so if you aren't forced to use eclipse, you should begin trying netbeans first I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To heck with eclipse.. I found a way of getting Visual Studio to compile C++ projects as C projects.. much better... after spending so many hours trying to get the IDE working with all its quirks... I don't think I'll be going back to that again (at least not for anything C anyway).

For anyone interested:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/16256/compiling-c-in-visual-studio.net

Basically:

1. Go to project properties
2. Go to C/C++ node
3. Select "Advanced" subnode
4. Go to property "Compile As" and select option "Compile as C Code (/TC)"
5. Click OK and go back to solution explorer..
6. Change file extensions from .cpp to .c

That's it..

Comment: How is this related to question ? And with Eclipse ?